# How to suppress arbitrary warn/error messages from DBI?

Tags: perl

code:

```
# A:
$dbh->do(qq/insert into foo(cl) values('test')/);
# B:
$dbh->do(qq/insert into foo(cl) values('test')/) or warn $dbh->errstr;
# C:
eval { $dbh->do(qq/insert into foo(cl) values('test')/); };
warn "error : $@ " if $@;
```

All would output :

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'cl' at a.pl line 9.
```

I dont want this arbitrary warning/error message send to stderr. I'd like use `warn $dbh->errstr`.

`perl a.pl 2>/dev/null` would suppress the error message, but I want to know how to do this in script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install your own error handler. E.g.

```
$dbh->do($statement, { HandleError => \&handle_error });
```

Error handlers are described in [DBI POD](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.617/DBI.pm#HandleError)

Another options are to:

- Set `PrintWarn` attribute to *false* value (courtesy of Sinan's answer on some forum
- Trap all warnings via a signal handler: `$SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub {};`

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays I typically do the following

1. Always pass `RaiseError => 1`, `PrintError => 0` when creating a DBI handle. Now you don't have to add an error handler to every DBI call.
2. For statements where I am unconcerned about Duplicate key errors, catch and ignore that exception:

   ```
   use Try::Tiny;
   try { $dbh->do(...) }
   catch { die $_ unless /execute failed: Duplicate entry/ };
   ```

This is the best way I've found - `INSERT IGNORE` ignores *all* errors, not just duplicate key errors, and `REPLACE` will overwrite the existing row using a delete and insert. `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id` could possibly used, but I think catching the error is more explicit.